# Image not centering in IE8 when using max-width?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have a table that contains an image, but for some reason I cannot get certain images to center correctly. When I apply `max-width:170px` the image resizes correctly, but it does not center. In every other browser (even IE7) everything looks good, but IE8 chokes. Here is the FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/5VT7e/.

Note: I created the fiddle in Chrome, but went to view it in IE8 and I guess JSFIDDLE doesn't work in IE8. None-the-less you can view all the code ;)

Here's a screen shot of the problem:

**Problem:**
[image]

**Desired:**
[image]

- First image looks okay
- Second image is shifted to the right
- Third image looks okay
- Fourth image is shifted to the right
- Fifth image is shifted to the right

Pretty much any image that `max-width:170px` effects is shifted to the right.

Thanks for having a look.

Comment: possible duplicate of [IE8 non-compatibility mode, image with max-width and height:auto](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771176/ie8-non-compatibility-mode-image-with-max-width-and-heightauto)

Comment: My problem deals with tables, but not sure if that matters.

Comment: It's unlikely (but not impossible) that it matters.  Try setting a width (perhaps `auto` or `100%`) on the parent container (`td` in this case).

Comment: Iv'e tried setting the width in every possible manner (in the td, img, and thru css) still nothing.

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1771176/ie8-non-compatibility-mode-image-with-max-width-and-heightauto) provides two possible solutions:

1. Set `width: auto` on your images
2. Provide a width on the **direct** parent element of the images.